# Node and Firebase Cloud Messaging TypeError

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Keep receiving a TypeError and I cant figure out why. I installed Firebase by using (`npm install firebase --save`). Here is my code:

```
    var firebase = require("firebase"); // Firebase
var express = require('express'); // Express instaniated a different way for serving static webpages
var app = express(); // Express App include

    // Set port
    app.listen(8085);

    // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
            apiKey: "AIza...............",
            authDomain: ".....firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "...............",
            storageBucket: "..........appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "..............."
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);

    // Create the URL for using Firebase
    app.get('/fcmtest', function (req, res) {

        const messaging = firebase.messaging();
        messaging.requestPermission()
            .then(function () {
                console.log("Have Permission")
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log("Do Not Have Permission");
            });
    });
```

This is the error I am receiving. InitializeApp seems to be working fine but messaging is not working. (npm -v firebase) spits out 3.10 but the npm webpage says the latest is 3.6.1.

```
TypeError: firebase.messaging is not a function
   at /usr/gserv/services/app.js:226:32
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/gserv/services/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at next (/usr/gserv/services/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
   at Route.dispatch (/usr/gserv/services/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/gserv/services/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at /usr/gserv/services/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
   at Function.process_params (/usr/gserv/services/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
   at next (/usr/gserv/services/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
   at /usr/gserv/services/node_modules/connect-busboy/index.js:14:14
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/gserv/services/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase

> "Firebase Cloud Messaging is not included in the server side Firebase npm module. Instead, you can use the Firebase Cloud Messaging Rest API."

So you should make rest calls for messaging, but you cannot use the messaging function in the code like you tried.

See the REST API documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#http_post_request

Comment: I wasnt attempting to send a message. My first step in setting up firebase is to request notification permission from the user using the process in this video (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client). I need to get permission first, and then I can grab a users token for sending messages later.

Comment: But the code to request permission must run in the user's browser, not in the server-side node.js process.